# Use TLS 1.2 with codification TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 over schannel on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to create a C# client that works on Windows Server 2012 R2 using C# and a TLS 1.2 protocol with `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` encoding.

The problem is that on Windows Server 2012 R2 this codification doesn't appear on available ciphers ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1)). I have tried to include the cipher in the Windows list as in the Microsoft article ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls)) but it doesn't work.

I notice the article says that C# typical classes like API `System.Net` (for example, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and `System.Net.Security.SslStream`) use `SCHANNEL` in the background.

Is there another way of connecting to an API without using this `SCHANNEL`?
I strongly believe that there is because I can access the API through Postman and Chrome Browser which indicates that both applications access the API in a direct way without using the cipher provided (`SCHANNEL`) by the operating system.

Comment: You can't use TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 without patching. Once you patch, *supported* .NET Framework versions, ie 4.6.2 and later, will use it by default. All supported .NET Framework/Core versions use the best available TLS algorithm out of the box. On Windows 11 that means TLS 1.3

Comment: Why are you using Windows Server 2012 R2 though? It reaches [end of support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-server-2012-r2-end-of-support) in October 2023. The problem may not exist at all in supported Windows Server versions

Comment: If you're stuck wit 2012R2 until October, the only way to use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is to ensure the OS is fully patched (otherwise the algorithm won't be available) and use either .NET Core or Framework 4.6.2+

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been doing some research and I'm afraid that on Windows 2012 the proper cipher is not available. I would need a workaround to avoid making a secure connection the same way Postman does: "SSL certificate verification = false" is this possible from C#?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't find the proper patch for the server, do you know which is it?